# @Where not working with @onetoone in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a requirement where @OneToOne association should be fetched according to certain condition.

```
class Entity2 {
    @OneToOne
    @Where(clause="epoch_end_time > current_timestamp() ")
    @JoinColumn(name="program_index",insertable=false,updatable=false,nullable=false)
    private ProgramHistory pgmHistory;
} 

class Entity1 {

@OnetoMany
@JoinColumn(...........)
private Entity2 entity;

}
```

When I execute "from Entity1"..Hibernate creates query which has the condition like below "..........,Entity2.proram_index = ProgramHistory.program_index"...But I need @Where clause as well has to be added as part of this query.But hibernate never seems adduing it.Any idea? Is there any alternative to @Where..I my case epoch_end_time is a coloum in ProgramHistory  table.

@Where working fine with @OneToMany...But my requirement is to put condition in assosicated entity of @OneToOne. Would @Filter help? Documentation says @Where and @Filter is meant for Collection.

Answer (score 2):

@Where and @Filter meant for collection.So it will not work with @OneToOne.